# Assign the inner loop result into a variable

Tags: django-templates

I have a loop like this in my django template and this having an inner loop

```
       {% for productinfo in product_list %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{productinfo.attr}}</td>
            <td>
               <select class="form-control seller-combo" name="category">
                <option value="">Select Attributes</option>
                  {% for attr in product_list %}
                    <option value="{{attr|mongo_id}}">{{ attr.attr }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
              </select> 
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

My problem is that each time when the outer loop is running the inner loop also run many times. I want to remove the inner loop from this and want to call this inner loop before the  outer loop is running.

Like example the code should be like this,

```
                  {% for attr in product_list %}
                    <option value="{{attr|mongo_id}}">{{ attr.attr }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
```

And assign the result of this code into a variable say it as `result`

Then attach this `result` like this,

```
         {% for productinfo in product_list %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{productinfo.attr}}</td>
                <td>
                   <select class="form-control seller-combo" name="category">
                    <option value="">Select Attributes</option>
                      {{result}}
                  </select> 
                </td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Doing like this i can increase my code performance

Answer (score 1):

> {% for attr in product_list %}

`<option value="{{attr|mongo_id}}">{{ attr.attr }}</option>`

> {% endfor %}

make this as a seperate template this.html and `{% include 'this.html' %}`

OR

to increase the performance use with tag

> {% with product_list as p_list %}
>
> "write your for loop"
>
> {% endwith %}